# Is there evidence to exercise a little before Iftar?

Tags: ramadan, sawm, human-body, iftar

Some brothers go to the gym during their fast and work out for around an hour before breaking the fast. I read there is some benefit for the body / losing weight / etc doing this. I'm wondering if there is any evidence in the Hadith on this however?

Comment: Why do you need evidence for it? You don't need a hadith for every action you want to perform.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is just a practical constraint.

- If we exercise during daylight, it may be too hot, and we can't drink to [rehydrate](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-treat-dehydration) until iftar.  We may also need to go to work.
- It might be impractical to exercise at night.  E.g. the gyms are closed, people tend to sleep at night.  Moreover, eating a large meal at iftar can make it hard to exercise afterwards.
- And there's perhaps an *I'm so hungry, I can't do anything that requires thinking* period before breaking the fast.

There's indeed a benefit for the body in exercising, and it helps lose weight.  But there's nothing Islam-specific about this.

Some "exercise during Ramadan" advice:

> The best time to weight train during Ramadan is after taraweeh prayers at night. ... If this is too late then **the next best time to weight train is about 1 hour after iftar before tarawih prayer**. -- [virtualmosque.com](http://www.virtualmosque.com/personaldvlpt/worship-personaldvlpt/fasting-ramadan/the-ramadan-nutrition-and-workout-plan-for-success-by-rehan-jalali-the-protein-shaikh/)
>
> If you can, get in about 25 minutes of exercise right before sehri/suhoor. This way you do not dehydrate your body while working out during you fast, and you are able to fuel yourself right away. However I realise this is not feasible for everyone, so **another option is spending another 25 minutes just before iftar**. -- [islamgreatreligion.wordpress.com](https://islamgreatreligion.wordpress.com/2011/07/26/7-top-tips-for-exercising-in-ramadan/)

Judging from various sites ([1](https://www.islamreligion.com/articles/1904/health-in-islam-part-4/); [2](https://theislamicworkplace.com/2011/12/01/follow-the-sunna-of-the-prophet-s-how-exercise-benefits-the-brain-and-overall-performance/); [3](https://islamqa.info/en/40527); [4](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-about-islam/what-is-the-islamic-view-of-sports-and-exercise/)) that talk about hadiths relating to exercise, there's nothing like what is asked for in the question.  You can find things like *Teach your children swimming, archery and horse riding* ([ref.](https://hadithanswers.com/teach-your-children-swimming-archery-and-horse-riding/)) and *A strong believer is better and is more lovable to Allah than a weak believer* ([Sahih Muslim 2664](https://sunnah.com/muslim/46/52)), but these don't relate to exercise before iftar.